# Event-Time Temporal Table Join requires both primary key and row time attribute in versioned table, but no row time attribute can be found

Tags: join, apache-flink, flink-sql, temporal

I have tried to use lookup join but i find this problem:

```
SELECT
>   e.isFired,
>   e.eventMrid,
>     e.createDateTime,
>   r.id AS eventReference_id,
>     r.type
> FROM Event e
> JOIN EventReference FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF e.createDateTime AS r
>   ON r.id = e.eventReference_id;
```

**[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Event-Time Temporal Table Join requires both primary key and row time attribute in versioned table, but no row time attribute can be found.**

Answer (score 2):

Whether that query will be interpreted by the Flink SQL planner as a temporal join or a lookup join depends on the type of the table on the right-hand side. In this case I guess you haven't used a lookup source. And your time attribute might not be defined correctly.

Temporal (time-versioned) joins require

- an equality predicate on the primary key of the versioned table
- a time attribute

and lookup joins require

- a lookup source connector, (e.g., JDBC, HBase, Hive, or something custom)
- an equality join predicate
- using a processing time attribute in combination with
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF (to prevent needing to update the join results)

Comment: oh, dear, I thought every table could be lookup source.